# How to change the compile version in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I always use eclipse to build an android project. When I use the eclipse to start a new project, I can choose the compile version. But in Android Studio, I can only choose the min version when I start a new module. I tried to change the `compileSdkVersion`  in `build.gradle`. But when I clean the project ,I got a lot of errors.Most of them are something like `No resource found that matches the given name ....`

Here is my build.gradle

```
compileSdkVersion 16
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"`
```

So my question is :How can I assign the compile version when I start the new module at the first time just like what I always do in the eclipse ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Open your project;
2. Choose menu item *File->Project Structure*, and click your modules (like MyApp), and you will find "Compile Sdk Version" in *Properties* tab.